# dragging object from html page using (using javascript) into a flash container?

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I am doing some pre-production on a project that requires drawing on a 3d canvas, which I think flash is the best way to go. But there is a chance down the line that this client might want the site to show up on the ipad, iphone or other mobile devices that don't support flash.

So I was playing with the idea of doing everything in html and javascript except for the actual drawing/3D area. Almost like using flash as the  element. I think html5 is too premature to start using this, but might be beneficial down the line.  Chances are I will just go the entire flash route, but I thought it would be interesting to try.

Anyway, my question is pretty top level. 1) how hard would it be to drag an object from an html page using javascript, and dropping it into the flashplayer. And then manipulating it from there.

Are there any examples out there that have tried to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Communication between Flash and an HTML page requires the use of [`ExternalInterface`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html). That's a good place to start. [These guys](http://techblog.floorplanner.com/2008/11/06/dragndrop-from-html-to-flash/) seem to have figured out some of the details.

As far as the iPad and iPhone are concerned, Flash just [ain't gonna happen](http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/).

However, I don't think it's fair to say HTML5 is "too premature". [Lots](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/detail/juicydrop-liu5nh/) of [people](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/detail/bomomo/) are [doing lots](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/detail/aquarium/) of [cool things](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/detail/sketchpad/) with the [canvas](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/detail/javascript-canvas-raytracer/) [element](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/detail/depth-of-field/). You could too. :)

Comment: Yeah I don't think flash is going to happen for the ipad, and when I mean premature I just mean the cross-browser problem.  I know I can do everything I need with html5, but if the majority of the audience can't see it, then it won't work. So, I want to fall back on flash for that part, and then in phase 2 possibly use canvas for modern browsers. But htanks for the link